# Installing D-Link DWA-131 (13.10)

Tags: wireless, drivers, 13.10, usb-modem

I found this thread:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/439901/how-do-i-install-a-d-link-dwa-131

But it has been closed. One comment referred to this guide:

http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/277-ubuntu-precise-dwa-131-rev-b1

But it doesn't work.

To begin, the guide is for this:

```
package barcode showing H/W Ver.:B1 F/W Ver.:2.00
```

But my package has

```
package barcode showing H/W Ver.:B1 F/W Ver.:2.01
```

As for the vendor ID of

```
2001 and Device ID 330d
```

I can't see either of those numbers on the box or in the example shown in the guide.

Next, the guide talks about updating the kernel but the kernel I am running is already higher:

My kernel

```
Linux connor 3.11.0-19-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 11 18:48:34 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My version

```
connor@connor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:    13.10
Codename:   saucy
```

When I do the next step `sudo modprobe rtl8192cu swenc=1` there's no output

Then the next `echo "2001 330D" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu/new_id` this is the output

```
2001 330D
```

My lsusb

```
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 2001:330d D-Link Corp.
```

I've also been trying this thread

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2200493&page=2&p=12978483#post12978483

I did the driver update instruction, it seemed to update but when I reboot still no light coming on the USB device

Next I try this command

```
lsmod
iwconfig
ifconfig -a
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

This is the output

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 69130  0 
crct10dif_pclmul       14289  0 
crc32_pclmul           13113  0 
lrw                    13286  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
ath9k                 155907  0 
ath9k_common           13859  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              444732  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    23827  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              597268  1 ath9k
cfg80211              480503  3 ath,ath9k,mac80211

connor@connor:~$ iwconfig

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

connor@connor:~$ ifconfig -a

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 24:fd:52:79:9c:53  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
```

**Does anyone know how to get this device working?**

---

Update:

**lsusb** output, with/without *USB modem* attached (*difference only*)

```
connor@connor:~$ lsusb

Bus 003 Device 013: ID 2001:330d D-Link Corp.
```

**dmesg** output, last 20 lines

Comment: Check out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/432640/will-dwa-131-work-after-installing-drivers-with-ndiswrapper Same USB ID, and works with **13.10** 'rtl8192cu' driver.

Comment: @david6 I tried editing the original to add the dmesg output but it exceeded the character limit so added output to comment

Comment: OK, can't give the dmesg output anywhere, it's too long. What should I be looking for in the output @david6?

Comment: @david6 - had a look at the link you provided. I'm a total n00b and don't know how to do anything much - how do I make it use the rtl8192cu driver?

Comment: @david6 Updated original with the requested outputs

Comment: Can confirm the apt-get command, tried it earlier today, it updated but didn't help. Have tried again since and terminal says everything is up to date @david6

Comment: No output from mesg | grep -e 8188c -e rtw -e 131

Comment: Added output from dmesg | grep -e 8188c -e rtw -e 131 to original

Comment: It is clearly referenced `echo "2001 330D" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu/new_id` notice "2001 330D" which refers to the vendor id 2001 and Device ID 330d

Answer (score 1):

Am on 14.04 with same DWA131-B1 adapter, used [this driver](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes) (follow instructions there) and added 8192cu to `/etc/modules` and

```
echo "2001 330D" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu/new_id
```

to `/etc/rc.local` (note that this still uses the 'rtl') [as per this](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/277-ubuntu-precise-dwa-131-rev-b1) so far stable and fast without `swenc=1`

Comment: I agree, the swenc=1 was just a precautionary measure because nobody had really tested it out at the time.

Answer (score 0):

### Prerequisites:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Output from, that changes with/without the USB modem inserted.

```
lsusb
```

eg. (as you have already supplied)

> **Bus 003 Device 006: ID 2001:330d D-Link Corp.**

---

### Try the following

```
dmesg

sudo rfkill unblock all
sudo modprobe rtl8192cu

dmesg
```

What you are looking for is: *What (if anything) was added to the **dmesg** output, after the driver (rtl8182cu) was loaded to memory.*

Comment: where should I post the output, in the comments here or do I need to edit your answer?

Comment: The apt-get command gives same output with or without USB attached: linux-firmware-nonfree is already the newest version.

Comment: With the command you've given me, should each line be entered separately or do I just copy and past the whole lot into terminal?

Comment: OK, so I ran each command separately - the output is ridiculously large (three A4 pages in Libre Office) but a lot seems to be different - too much for me to be able to tell you what has changed witht he limited number of characters available. For instance the last line said:

[20191.291350] ata3: EH complete

Now it says:

[20466.037120] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready

Comment: I've added the lsusb outputs both with and without USB attached in my original post

Comment: Any lines after **[20191.291350]** (which is a timestamp) might be interesting. Anything about **wlan0:** is definitely important.

Comment: It's all gibberish to me but here is an example of how different the output is.

The first few lines 'before'

`[    0.965230] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002 
[    0.965231] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1 
[    0.965232] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller 
[    0.965234] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.11.0-19-generic ehci_hcd 
[    0.965235] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0 
[    0.965307] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found 
[    0.965310] hub 1-0:1.0: 2 ports detected 
`

Comment: And after:

  `121.854481] ata6: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4090800 action 0xe frozen
[  121.854491] ata6: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
[  121.854497] ata6: SError: { HostInt PHYRdyChg 10B8B DevExch }
[  121.854507] ata6: hard resetting link
[  122.575322] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[  122.575355] ata6: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[  122.576820] ata6.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[  122.576824] ata6.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out`

Comment: And the last few lines before:

`[  134.742013] ata6.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded 
[  134.742018] ata6.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out 
[  134.742020] ata6.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out 
[  134.742161] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133 
[  134.743410] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133 
[  134.757184] ata3: EH complete 
[  134.757190] ata6: EH complete`

Comment: Last few lines after:

`[  382.913377] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[  382.914011] ata6.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[  382.914016] ata6.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[  382.914018] ata6.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[  382.915375] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/33
[  382.921452] ata3.00: configured for PIO0
[  382.929350] ata6: EH complete
[  382.937409] ata3: EH complete
[  384.955818] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu`

Comment: wlan isn't mentioned in the 'before' dmesg, here is the relevant lines from the 'after' 

`[  370.354750] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/33
[  370.367263] ata6: EH complete
[  370.371293] ata3: EH complete
[  371.158607] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  371.315551] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  382.188034] ata3: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4090800 action 0xe frozen
[  382.188047] ata3: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
[  382.188055] ata3: SError: { HostInt PHYRdyChg 10B8B DevExch }
[  382.188067] ata3: hard resetting link`

Comment: Actually, my bad, wlan is mentioned in the before output here:

`[   16.098171] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready 
[   16.173786] alx 0000:04:00.0: irq 49 for MSI/MSI-X 
[   16.173860] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready 
[   16.174659] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready 
[   16.186648] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready 
[   16.575022] type=1400 audit(1396783499.052:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" parent=886 profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=894 comm="apparmor_parser" `

Comment: Please add to your *question*, with prefix of <sp><sp><sp><sp> (for each line). (Or just paste in, best effort).

Answer (score 0):

The default kernel driver is weak and gets a range of maybe 2-5 meters with a clear line of sight to the AP.

I have this card and it works great when you use the newer firmware from realtek. The original new firmware won't build properly on kernels >=3.10 however, patched versions are available from github.

Here are the instructions:

**12.04 & 14.04+: you can view [these](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/277-ubuntu-precise-dwa-131-rev-b1) instructions or just do as I say.**

(use these instructions when your wireless USB device [rtl8192cu] is not automatically recognized by Ubuntu)

```
sudo modprobe rtl8192cu
echo "2001 330D" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu/new_id
echo "rtl8192cu" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Then, edit /etc/rc.local by opening the file with your favorite text editor like in this example:

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

make sure it says . . .

```
echo "2001 330D" | tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu/new_id

exit 0
```

You can use the wireless now or, alternatively, you can make sure you have all of your work saved before you type:

```
sudo reboot
```

Your wireless driver should start up automatically.

---

**To compile and install the proprietary Realtek 8192cu driver, run the following commands in an open terminal:**

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git build-essential linux-headers-generic dkms
git clone https://github.com/dz0ny/rt8192cu.git --depth 1
cd rt8192cu
sudo make dkms
```

For hard installation use:

```
make
sudo make install
```

instead of `sudo make dkms` .

To enable this driver, use the command:

```
sudo modprobe 8192cu
```

Finally, update /etc/modules with this command before you reboot:

```
echo '8192cu' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

---

[Souce #1: bernaerts.dyndns.org](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/277-ubuntu-precise-dwa-131-rev-b1)

[Source #2: github.com/dz0ny](https://github.com/dz0ny/rt8192cu)

Answer (score 0):

Try this - https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential

git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git

cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver

sudo make

sudo make install
```