# Can't get wireless dongle DWA 131 to work on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, usb

I recently got a D-link DWA-131 wireless usb dongle to work on my desktop PC. I was in quite a hurry when I chose it, but considering the abundant documentation on how to successfully get it to work on Ubuntu, I assumed I wouldn't have too much trouble with it. Silly me. >_<

Here's the situation:

- I am running up-to-date Ubuntu 14.04 on a desktop PC.
- The device is properly detected (listed in lsusb) but does not work out of the box.
- I have all the required packages for the methods mentioned below.

I tried three methods, following every step, and nothing seems to work.

When trying [bernaerts's](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/277-ubuntu-precise-dwa-131-rev-b1) method I got this (in French):

```
install: impossible d'évaluer «8712u.ko»: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
make: *** [install] Erreur 1
```

Which (more or less) means:

```
install: impossible to evaluate "8712u.ko": No such file or directory
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

So I dug for a fix, found nothing conclusive, tried to find another solution and ended up on [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443886/installing-d-link-dwa-131-13-10) where I found [pvaret's](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes) - which does not work any better for me.

After the failure of pvaret's solution, I un-blacklisted the native driver in /etc/modprob.d/ and eventually tried something else from askubuntu.com: adding the following line in /etc/modprobe.d/network_drivers.conf as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/564716/cannot-get-my-n300-dwa-130-d-link-wireless-usb-to-work-on-ubuntu-14-04):

```
install rt2800usb /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install rt2800usb $CMDLINE_OPTS; /bin/echo "2001 3c25" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2800usb/new_id
```

Which got me nothing more, even with

```
sudo modprobe rt2800usb
```

and a reboot.

I'm quite desperate now so if any of you has any idea why none of these work, or on how to get this dongle to function, I'd be glad to read your input!

Comment: These are all different drivers and apply to separate devices. They cannot be used interchangeably. Please edit your question to add the result of: lsusb Thanks.